# android: how to pass values from one broadcast receiver to another?

Tags: java, android

i have this broadcastreceiver that executes some code from time to time and triggers itself again by setting a timer (alarmmanager). the result of the calculations is an integer value, which should be used as input for the next time the algorithm is executed. therefore, i need to store this value.

i don't want to do this with SQLite as this would produce an enormous overhead - but what are the alternatives? manage this via shared preferences? store it within files?

any good ideas?

Comment: I think SharedPreferences would be a simple and correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carry the data around in the PendingIntent you specify to the AlarmManager.  However, instead of a repeating alarm, you might need to set a new alarm each time.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably put a broadcast pending intent into the alarm manager, and create that pending intent with an Intent that stores the int value you want to carry over. You would create the pending intent with [PendingIntent.getBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29), with the data intent as an argument. Your receiver would receive this intent and get the int value out of it.